# Checking condition in upper level tag in xslt v2.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have this requirement that I only need to populate the `<Group>` tag under the `<Section>`, if the `<Group>` tag under the `<Data>` is not present. I can't get the correct output that I want. For example:

**INPUT**

```
<Record>
<Data>
    <ID>1234DFD57</ID>
    <Group>
        <abc-KD>243fds</abc-KD>
    </Group>
    <Section>
        <ID>33-2311</ID>
        <Group>
            <abc-KD>NORM</abc-KD>
        </Group>
        <Date>2017-03-25</Date>
    </Section>
    <Date>2017-03-25</Date>
</Data>
</Record>
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
<Record>
<Data>
    <ID>1234DFD57</ID>
    <Group>
        <abc-KD>243fds</abc-KD>
    </Group>
    <Section>
        <ID>33-2311</ID>
        <Date>2017-03-25</Date>
    </Section>
    <Date>2017-03-25</Date>
</Data>
</Record>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Section">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="ID"/>
        <xsl:if test="normalize-space(string(../Group)) = ''">
            <xsl:copy-of select="Group"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Date"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Your feedback is highly appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current stylesheet does the work. More efficient way would be:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <!-- identity transform template -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- do nothing for the Group -->
    <xsl:template match="Section[normalize-space(parent::Data/Group) != '']/Group"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The identity transform template is the one that copies every node in the xml, while recursively processing them in document order, as it is.
The second template matches the `Group` elements with the desired condition and does nothing for it, hence omitting them in the output.

The x-path in the `@match` does the trick:
`Section[normalize-space(parent::Data/Group) != '']/Group`

It matches those `Section/Group` elements under `Data` whose `Group` doesn't exist or has null value(excluding space characters).

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Can you explain how to template is for? I'm sorry, I'm still learning the basic part and I can't understand the solution that you've did. Thank you.

Comment: @AltheaVeronica Please check out the explanation added.